# OTRS: Reports, how to include notes and resolution notes?

Tags: otrs

I need to export a report every Monday for my supervisor, I can't seem to figure out the way to include notes and resolution notes for the tickets in the report. Even though I can include notes as a column, when I export the report nothing show.

Please advise, thank you!

Mon

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a ticket list object for your statistics and want to add an article note, email or something like this to the output.

Unfortunately you can't add Article Values like comments and such stuff to the default stats. You need to develop your own "static" Statistics module or use a db query to get the needed values.

Sorry for that.

regards

Johannes